# Mergelog program

Tags: python, logging, merge

I need help creating a program that can merge two files, and return information about user activity.

I have to create a took that takes parameters, two file names, and a user name that will then merge the two lists and print out in chronological order the activities of the given user. 
Say there were several users in the log file, it should be able to ask for one and then print out in order that persons activity, can anyone help please? 
Here's what i have:

```
def main():
  l1, l2 = rFile()
  sLogs = sortLogs(l1, l2)
  printLogs(sLogs)


def printLogs(log):
  for i in range(0, len(log), 1):
    print("sLogs["",i,": ", log[i], end="", sep="")

def rFile():
  l1Name = input("First file to read: ")
  l2Name = input("Second file to read: ")
  log1 = read(l1Name)
  log2 = read(l2Name)
  return log1, log2

def read(fname):
  return open(fname, "r").readlines()

def sortLogs(log1, log2):
  mLog = log1 + log2
  for i in range(0, len(mLog), 1):
    for j in range(i, len(mLog), 1):
      if(mLog[i] > mLog[j]):
      temp = mLog[j]
      mLog[j] = mLog[i]
      mLog[i] = temp
  return mLog

main()
```

The problem im having is taking a username and only printing out that user's activity

The log files are formatted the same way, like below:

```
12:34:23 Whom Logged In 
13:12:23 Who Opened Terminal
14:23:23 Who Logged Out
```

etc..

I know you could sort them by tokens, which if you use a "" as the token seperator you can do it by the first token, which would be the time, but im not quite sure how to write that exactly

Comment: So what did you try for week? Show us some of the code you tried. A good start would be to open 2 files and try to compare them line by line as it is in documentation http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon. It wouldn't be a bad idea to show what the two files look like (say 5 lines from each file). Are the entries in the two files formatted the same way? How would you know which part of an entry is a user name? How would you know which user you are trying to find data for? Are the time stamps in the two files formatted the same? Can a simple string comparison place them in chronological order, or do you have to do computation on the date strings to get the results sortable? How big are the files (KiB, MiB, GiB, bigger)?